# Spring Session is being recreated

Tags: spring, session, spring-session

We are using Spring session and we observed that the screen was appearing blank sometimes. We noticed that when the screen worked as expected, there was only one session id created. However, when the screen was blank, we noticed two session id being created because of which the data stored in the session was getting lost.

Please let me know if anyone has encountered such issue before and found a solution to it.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you post what the Session cookie looks like when it fails? Does that session exist and does it contain the values you expect? Do you have a sample that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Did you get this figured out? We are planning on going GA soon and I would really like to make sure your issue is fixed before GA.